# Difficulties installing ITK4.10.0 as rusage be no longer used

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to install itk4.10.0 version, However, I am getting the following error. I have attempted to google the answer but have not found anything. Any and all help would be very much appreciated!

```
**InsightToolkit-4.10.0/Modules/Core/Common/src/itkMemoryUsageObserver.cxx:449:79: error: ‘struct rusage’ has no member named ‘ru_ixrss’
     return static_cast<MemoryUsageObserverBase::MemoryLoadType> (resourceInfo.ru_ixrss);**
```

I checked the man age of getusage, there it seems they stopped maintaining the  "ru_ixrss (unmaintained)
This field is currently unused on Linux".

Comment: Going onto the itk.org web site, I see a very prominent link called "Online Discussion" which leads to a forum of experienced users of this library. Don't you think you're far more likely to quickly get answers and help with your highly specialized problem from other users of this same library, instead of a general web site like Stackoverflow?

Comment: I checked there are lot of people who asked their question, but the question remains same and couldn't anyone given answer. so I thought let's ask on global forum.

Comment: Presuming there is no configuration option that results in the shown code not getting compiled, the only solution would be to patch the code yourself.

Comment: Thanks @SamVarshavchik for your reply, but I didn't see any configuration option in code. Just wanted to know is there any alternate option of ru_ixrss

Comment: Then the only obvious option is to change the code to have it return a fixed value of some kind, that makes the rest of the code work normally.

Comment: the original code is look like MemoryUsageObserverBase::MemoryLoadType
SysResourceMemoryUsageObserver::GetMemoryUsage()
{

  struct  rusage resourceInfo;
  const int who = RUSAGE_SELF;
  if ( getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &resourceInfo) == 0 )
    {
    return static_cast<MemoryUsageObserverBase::MemoryLoadType> (resourceInfo.ru_ixrss);
    }

  return 0;
}
above one